# Android studio 3.0 Beta4 can't rename a file and build error sometimes

Tags: android, gradle

1. Rename Error :

   [image]
2. Build Error :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'D:\AndroidStudioWorkSpace\qianfan-android\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-support\debug\package_slice_7\dex-renamer-state.txt'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65032914), which, per the [last comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65032914#comment18):

> Beta 4 doesn't include the fix. It will be in beta 5.

Comment: I'm not good at English, Thanks for your answer very much! Next time I will get the answer from Google Issue Tracker first.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this same problem happening to a multidex apk using 3.0.1 My project is far from trivial so I have no idea where to go with this beyond just doing a stupid clean whenever it happens.... no rhyme or reason behind it as best as I can tell.